# Fix user is not in sudoers file without recovery mode

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have a virtual machine running on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.5 that is running in an air gapped system and I do not have physical access to it. Due to some misconfiguration, the only user in the VM is now no longer in the sudoers file and I have lost all root access to this system.

Several solutions posted suggested for me to boot in recovery mode and re-add the user back from root shell prompt. However this is not possible as I do not have access to the boot menu. I can only SSH into the VM via a VPN.

May I know how I can resolve this given my limitations?

Comment: if you can only access your machine via ssh with a user without root access, then wouldn't it be a gaping security hole if you could somehow still manage to get root access? i fear physical access to the machine is the only solution... can't you access VM host and start from there?

Comment: I came across your question when searching for a related question and also noticed you've visited the site recently (perhaps searching for other information).  Since I doubt you are still having this particular problem, could I suggest you either (a) post the solution you used, or (b) if you don't need an answer any longer, just delete the question?  Thanks!